# Linear code over $F_q$ exists always

Tags: finite-fields, coding-theory

Why is there always an $[n, n-1, 2]$ linear code over $F_q$ for any $n \geq 2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the code is equivalent to a code with systematic generator matrix
$$G = \left(\begin{array}{llllll}
g_{11} & g_{12}& \ldots & g_{1,n-2} & g_{1,n-1} & g_{1n}\\
0      & g_{22}&\ldots  & g_{2,n-2} & g_{2,n-1} & g_{2n}\\
\vdots \\
0      &  0    & \ldots & 0         & g_{n-1,n-1} & g_{n-1,n}
\end{array}\right),$$
where the (diagonal) entries $g_{11},\ldots,g_{n-1,n-1}$ are nonzero. From here you see directly that the code has dimension $n-1$ and minimum Hamming distance 2.

Comment: What a nice answer! Thanks a lot!

Comment: And how many binary linear codes with these parameters $[n, n-1, 2]$ do exist?

Answer (score 1):

This code satisfies the Singleton bound, so it is MDS. So its dual code is also MDS. Consider the parameters of its dual code. Do you recognise it?